# Does Key changes of different intervals have different effects?

Tags: theory, learning, jazz, key-signatures

Condisering Key Changes :
Does Key changes of different intervals produce different effects on the Audience similar to intervals?
Does Key changes have different quality to them and if so what are they called

Comment: For me any key change has an effect for two bars maximum, after which there's no real difference. Except when reading, when my brain is still in the previous key.

Comment: interesting, however the question is, does a key change from C to D have the same effect as C to D# or any other note. for example is there any such thing as a Tritone Key change

Comment: If you really need an answer - not for me, and often, except when witnessed by musicians,  key changes aren't even noticed.

Comment: @Tim - Don't laymen recognize truck driver's gear changes when they hear them, though?

Comment: @Dekkadeci - sometimes, not always.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do have different effects.

Often the difference is one of distance, or smoothness. A modulation from C to G will sound very smooth, because there's only one pitch that is different between C and G major. A modulation from C to F♯, though, will sound rather distant, because there's only one pitch in common between the two keys (there are sort of two pitches in common, but technically they're different: F and E♯).

But defining exactly what these qualities are is much more difficult and opinion-based. With that said, there are some modulations (or chord changes) that have been used with some consistency throughout history for particular effects. A common one is discussed by Richard Cohn [in this famous article](http://this%20famous%20article); he shows that motion between two "hexatonic poles," like C major and A♭ minor, is often used to express an "uncanny" effect in music by Wagner.